# Trouble with converting VBA to Python

Tags: python, vba

i have trouble with converting this code in VBA to python function. Always it counts bad control digit.

This is working VBA code :

```
Public Function kontrolna(liczba As String)
Dim l1, l2, k As Integer
If Len(liczba) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    l1 = 3
    l2 = 1
Else
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 3
End If
k = 0
For x = 1 To Len(liczba)
    If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
        k = k + (Val(Mid(liczba, x, 1)) * l1)
    Else
        k = k + (Val(Mid(liczba, x, 1)) * l2)
    End If
Next x
kontrolna = (10 - (k Mod 10)) Mod 10
End Function
```

And this is what i do in python but like i say it is wrong. Result for my function always is 2.
I try my best but no i have no more ideas how to fix it...

```
liczba ='900068082' #GOOD CONTROL DIGIT FOR THIS CODE IS 3
def kontrolna(liczba):
l1 = int
l2 = int
if len(liczba) % 2 == 0:
    l1 = 3
    l2 = 1
else:
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 3
k=0

for x in range(len(liczba)):
    if int(x) % 2 == 0:
        k = k + x * l1
    else:
        k = k + x * l2
   
kontrolna = (10 - (k %10)) % 10
```

Comment: The vba code works on string's digits values (`Val(Mid(liczba, x, 1)`). I don't know well Python, but I don't think your code does that. x is the character's index in the string, and you seems to be using it directly. `range(len(liczba)` returns a sequence from 0 to the length of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 minor issues:

1. `Mid(liczba, x, 1)` takes the part of String liczba, starting at x, with length 1. In other words: it checks each integer in the String. Hence, your for-loop needs to be changed.
2. In addition, `x` needs to incremented, since lists start at 0 in Python, but start at 1 in VBA.

```
for x in range(len(liczba)):
    val = int(liczba[x])
    if (x+1) % 2 == 0:
        k = k + val * l1
    else:
        k = k + val * l2
```